# Rendering problems missing styles after every update

Tags: android, android-studio, updates

I get the "Rendering problems. Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?" and the gradle resolving without end after every android studio update, making my entire code non runnable. Only solution is to just recreate my project. Is there any solution to this? It is really, really annoying.

Comment: I was also experiencing this error but it was because I put into the manifest.xml the following under the manifest tag: xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" and then under the application tag, I put in the following: tools:replace="android:theme". Once I deleted that and shut down AS and restarted it up, the xml worked perfectly and was able to render.

Answer (score 29):

Try to Invalidate Caches and Restart. In Android Studio go to the **File** menu and choose **Invalidate Caches / Restart** and confirm with **Invalidate and Restart**.

An image showing the appropriate menu item in Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: Had this issue on a new clean install of Android Studio on 18 Dec 2014. For anyone still interested, this fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks Vit for the quick and easy solution! Worked for me too on a clean install.

Answer (score 7):

Simply click on the `Refresh` icon:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, would you mind adding an explanation of why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but this may help others...
Had the same problem and had another Error below: failed to find '?attr/**textEdit**SuggestionItemLayout' with 9 similar errors not shown. The textEdit, which i made bold above made me thinking if the error had something to do with the TextView and if the missing styles relate to the TextView Styles. Although I had no more TextView´s in my Layout I gave it a try and added `<item name="android:textViewStyle" >@style/AppTheme</item>` and it worked, no more error messages to this. Maybe this can still help someone.

Happy coding

Comment: I had the same error but had to add:
`<item name="android:textEditSuggestionItemLayout" >@style/AppTheme</item>`
In styles.xml under the style that is referenced in AndroidManifest.xml